# Google Spreadsheet INDIRECT doesn't work anymore

Tags: google-sheets

I use the INIDRECT function in Google Spreadsheet to retrieve a defined cell range via the INDEX function. The formula in german declaration looks like this:

`=IF(ISTZAHL($P2955),$P2955*IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("projects_",$O2955,)),$B2955),1),"")`

All worked fine since a year and now it doens't work anymore.
If I use the INDIRECT formula only it shows me the following error:

> Parameter 1 of the function INDIRECT uses the value: "projects_GBP"
>   This is no valid range value.

If I specify the range value "projects_GBP" without INDIRECT function it will find the value.

Was there a change in the INDIRECT formula or why does my formula no longer work?

Comment: Please use English names of spreadsheet functions and don't mix Excel related tags for questions about Google Sheets unless the question involves interactions between both apps like converting a file from one format to another.

Answer (score 0):

Out of nowhere it works again like a charm. Nothing has been changed.
Seems like it was/is an error from google.